# Would you like to help shape up our site for Grand Theft Auto 5?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, editing

*GTA V* came out recently. It's quite popular, and [has resulted in a humongous traffic boost to Arqade](https://twitter.com/df07/status/382273720007413761), especially mobile traffic. In fact our mobile traffic was high enough to be over half the mobile traffic of Stack Overflow. That's still small compared to the behemoth itself, but in full proportion, the traffic jump is pretty huge and likeable.

With your help, we'd like to try and boost this further. We're going to be distributing ads across the network to point people towards Arqade (much like we did for *Fallout: New Vegas* and *StarCraft II* back long ago). In the mean time, if you could assist us by **checking in on the quality and clarity of the questions we have on [grand-theft-auto-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5)**, that would be swell. There's lots of posts with huge traffic, some in the five digits and even some in the six digits for visits in less than a week - but the Q&A could be touched up. If you don't own the game, just simple grammar fixes or organizational edits will help. If you do own the game, see what bonus stuff you can add to what is present, and clarify things which may need it. Think of it like a big clean up effort, except less for closing 'n' such and more for beautification.

Comment: I would be glad to help, but as it stands, I don't want anything to do with the game until I can play it myself on the PC. :(

Comment: @3ventic So in about 6 months / year you'll help? :p

Comment: @Lyrion Naturally.

Comment: @3ventic We'll probably see another boost in traffic anyway when GTA V finally launches on PC.

Comment: Too bad this means most "good" questions will have been asked by then...